# How can I have an optional value in macro rules?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm making a rust macro, that is getting big and can be invoked in different manners.

However, I'm struggling to make it match a specific pattern.

The macro goes like:

```
macro!(i32, f32, String)
```

Where it takes any number of types as parameters.

But I would like to parse the same expression, with a value of an `u32` in front:

```
macro!(123, i32, f32, String)
```

I can't find a way to parse an `u32` value before any numbers of types.

Comment: Have you tried `$n:literal, $($t:ty),*`?

Comment: Is the intention that the first argument is a literal or an expression? Don't forget you can always tweak the syntax like `$v:literal => ...`